# MKCircleView and lineDashPattern

Tags: iphone, ios

I want to create a lineDashPattern for an MKCircleView that shows four equally sized segments with gaps in-between.  I think the problem I'm having is that for MKCircleView, lineDashPattern is not using map points; neither is it using pixels.  Or my math is wrong.  I started with this for my overlay:

```
double radius = 100.0;
double mradius = radius * MKMapPointsPerMeterAtLatitude(coordinate.latitude);
double circumference = mradius * M_PI * 2.0;
double segment = circumference / 4.0;
double line = segment * 0.85;
double gap = segment - line;
MKCircle *circle = [MKCircle circleWithMapRect:[self boundingMapRect]];
self.overlayView = [[MKCircleView alloc] initWithCircle:circle];
overlayView.strokeColor = [UIColor blueColor];
overlayView.lineWidth = 5;
overlayView.lineDashPattern = @[[NSNumber numberWithDouble:line], [NSNumber numberWithDouble:gap]];
```

That churns out large numbers that don't leave me any gaps, but then basing the circumference on this doesn't help either, although it generates smaller, more believable numbers:

```
CGPoint point = [overlayView convertPoint:[mapView convertCoordinate:coordinate toPointToView:mapView] fromView:mapView];
double circumference = point.x * M_PI * 2.0;
```

Any ideas?